# How to disable ACE Editor's Find Dialog

Tags: javascript, html, ace-editor

I would like to disable the ACE Editor's find dialog, which is invoked by pressing the 
<kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> key combination when the editor has focus.

I've tried the following (among other things):

```
document.body.onkeydown = 
document.body.onkeyup = 
document.body.onkeypress = function(event) {      
    return false;
};
```

This prevents one from being able to type normally, but does not stop <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>A key</kbd> from being processed.

How do to prevent <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combination from being processed?

Ideally I would like to be able to prevent only the <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> combination, as I want to continue using the other <kbd>Command</kbd> key combinations.

I have set up a [JSFiddle for this question](http://jsfiddle.net/faceleg/S9CNT/).

Comment: I think you're approaching this wrong. You should be trying to disable the find dialog, not the key shortcut.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Andrei Andrushkevich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27797303/231788) is now a better and simpler solution.

---

You can redefine the command associated with the shortcut by using `editor.commands.addCommand`, and then just supply an empty function. This custom definition will take precedence over the built-in one. In this case:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: "unfind",
    bindKey: {
        win: "Ctrl-F",
        mac: "Command-F"
    },
    exec: function(editor, line) {
        return false;
    },
    readOnly: true
})
```

Here's the [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S9CNT/6/). I didn't find clear documentation, but [here's the `editor.commands` definition](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/ac0a26d33334d4704a306294a09a3b91555daf2a/lib/ace/editor.js#L75) and [here's where `.addCommands()` is](https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/blob/8b971619b73f23df37c8ef915bd76d656b711943/lib/ace/keyboard/hash_handler.js#L88-L102). (Note: code may have changed since this answer was written.)

*Edited as per jcubic's comment*

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much! Facepalming myself for nothing coming up with this myself.

Answer (score 25):

It's better to use 'removeCommand' instead of use 'addCommand' with fake handler

```
editor.commands.removeCommand('find');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like removeCommand because it removes it from the menu; typically you'll allow users to define their own keys and *some* users may want to add it back in. I started off thinking I didn't want to use the built-in but later on I decided that it had some advantages.

You can just clear the bind keys to disable it. You can do:

```
var find = editor.commands.byName['find'];
find.bindKey = {};
editor.commands.addCommand(find);
```

which will accomplish what you can also do the long way:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'find',
    bindKey: {},
    exec: editor.commands.byName['find'].exec
});
```

this way if you have a GUI for users to set their own key bindings "Find" will still be in the command list; it will just be disabled and the exec will still be there.

If you have your own find function, you should also use addCommand and put the logic to open your find window in the exec function:

```
editor.commands.addCommand({
    name: 'find',
    bindKey: { win:'Ctrl-F',mac:'Ctrl-F'},
    exec: function(){
        alert("My Function Here");
        openMyFinderModal();
    }
});
```